# $document_root not parsed in error_log location by nginx

Tags: linux, ubuntu, nginx

Is there a way to use the $document_root variable in the error_log location for nginx? There's specific mention of it being supported on the access_log location [in the wiki](http://wiki.nginx.org/HttpLogModule#access_log) but nothing about error_log. I'm guessing it's something to do with them being from different modules?

Just trying to avoid repeating myself in the conf, if there's a way to do it that would be great!

Darren

Answer (score 0):

### Is there a way to use the $document_root variable in the error_log location for nginx?

Unfortunately, no. If you've put a variable in a directive and it did not get interpolated, there's nothing you can do about it.

There is an [Nginx FAQ page](http://nginx.org/en/docs/faq/variables_in_config.html) regarding this exact topic, which says (abbreviated):

> Variables should not be used as template macros. Instead, a macro expansion and "include" directives should be used to generate configs more easily and it can be done with the external tools, e.g. sed + make or any other common template mechanism.

### Okay, but why do the docs specifically show variables used in the `access_log` directive?

You are correct in mentioning that the docs for `access_log` contain some variable usage.

**Begin speculation:** Some directives are more powerful than others. According to the Nginx documentation, the first argument for `access_log` can be a *path*, whereas the first argument for `error_log` can be a *file*. Here's an excerpt from the [access_log docs page](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_log_module.html#access_log):

```
server {
    root       /spool/vhost/data/$host;
    access_log /spool/vhost/logs/$host;
    ...
```

Both `root` and `access_log` can use the `$host` variable. Therefore, I believe arguments described as a *path* are able to do variable interpolation.